# Getting text from FinishedLabel in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to create a `TLabel` and get text from `FinishedLabel` to show transparency on text when show a custom background image on Finished Page.

I make the same with `FinishedHeadingLabel` and works perfectly, 
But it does not work with `FinishedLabel`, here is the code:

```pascal
BottomFinishedLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
BottomFinishedLabel.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Parent;
BottomFinishedLabel.Font := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Font;
BottomFinishedLabel.Caption := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption;
BottomFinishedLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.WordWrap;
InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.FinishedLabel, BottomFinishedLabel);
WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Visible := False;
```

This is what it show:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to do (with `TLabel`):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably copy the text too early.

The `FinishedLabel` is set only after [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

I.e. earliest you can read it is in [`CurPageChanged(wpFinished)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged) (or in [`ShouldSkipPage(wpFinished)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage)).

---

If you know what variant of the text shows, you can also read `msgFinishedRestartLabel`, `msgFinishedLabel` or `msgFinishedLabelNoIcons` + `msgClickFinish` using [`SetupMessage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setupmessage).